# Internet speed slows down after disconnecting from VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, internet-connection

My setup is as follows:

1. Cable modem/Router in bridge mode
2. Google WiFi connected directly to Modem (3 pack). Only primary is hardwired, the rest are wireless. Therefore the Google Wifi does all router and wireless duties.
3. Also from Google WiFi primary, hard wired to a simple switch
4. Switch then connects most PCs, and Apple TV in house

I work from home and average about 800 Mbps download.  I started noticing that after a day's usage of my work VPN (Global Protect), then disconnecting from the VPN, that my download speeds are between 20 and 40 Mbps.
I have tried rebooting all the devices, one at a time, and all at same time - to no effect.

This also affects the whole network; despite the MacBook being the only one using a VPN solution, my iPad also shows the same max download speed.

The only way I have found to fix it is to factory reset the modem,  then put it back into bridge mode. This immediately brings download speeds back to 800+ Mbps.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
While I don't have a real solution, here is what appears to be working at the moment.

1. Factory reset the provider (Rogers Canada) cable-modem/router (Hitron CODA-4582U)
2. Left 3 Google Wifi pucks as is.
3. This now puts me in a double nat situation, which seems fine for now, I only needed to forward a few ports for apps that couldn't handle it.
4. I have used both my VPN's for a few days, and I haven't yet fallen back to slow speeds.  I am consistently getting 800+ Mbps.

It occurs to me now, that while in bridge mode, is it possible the modem isn't responding to provider in the way the like, so they purposely throttle it ?

Comment: my first thought was that your ISP is throttling you but that's not really an answer : \

Comment: My first thought is that if this keeps happening, and a factor reset sovles the problem, that the ISP is indeed pushing a configuration file out causing the problem.  If you reconnect to the same VPN does the download speeds return to normal?  I would not expect a 200x decrease in speed due to DNS but I would also try using something other than your ISP's DNS.

Comment: When I reconnect to VPn, the download speeds do not return to normal. In fact, if anything, they are a little slower.

Comment: try other VPN services to see if it acts the same or it is your current VPN environment only.

Comment: Yes, it does appear to occur after long (a day or 2) use of any VPN. However, I might have band-aid fixed it (kinda), see update above